# for db2 on cloud, are things like runstats and reorgchk/reorg done automatically?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I am seeing some slow performance on a couple of my queries that run against my db2 on cloud instance.  When I had a local db2, I would try these tools to see if I could improve performance.  Now, with db2 on cloud, I believe I can run them using admin_cmd, however, if they are already being run automatically on my db objects, there is no point, but I am not sure how to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, Db2 on Cloud is a managed (as a Service) database offering. But this is for the general part, not for application-specific stuff. Backup / restore can be done without any application insights, but creating indexes, running runstats or performing reorgs is application-specific.

[Runstats can be invoked using admin_cmd](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023587.html). The same is true for [running reorg on tables and indexes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023582.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Db2 on Cloud does auto reorgs and runstats automatic. We do recommend running them manually, if you are running a lot of data loads to better the performance.